# Fill NAs by smoothing the peak values

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq(from=as.POSIXct(as.Date("2020-10-01")), 
                            to= as.POSIXct(as.Date("2020-10-02")) , by = 'hour'), 
               val = c(15,20,18,22,17,NA,NA,NA,80,14,23,16,19,21,NA,NA,60,18,15,20,22,19,NA,35,18))
```

There are uneven sequences of 'NA's followed by peak values e.g.: val =  80, 60 and 35 .

I would like to fill the 'NA's by smoothing the peak values. For example: in the first NA sequence, three NAs are followed by 80,  which equals four data points therefore, 80 is divided by 4 = 20 .

*Note: the peak values are NOT outliers, so the total sum of the data points should not change.*

If possible, I would like to fill the NAs with the above conditions while reserving the signal behavior (trend and seasonality).

Many thanks.

Comment: May we assume that the peak values always come after a sequence of `NA`'s, never before the sequence?

Comment: Yes, they always do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The following function fills sequences of `NA` values with the next non-`NA` value divided by the sequence length.

```
fill_na <- function(x){
  na <- is.na(x)
  r <- rle(na)
  div <- r$lengths[r$values] + 1L
  cs <- cumsum(r$lengths)[r$values]
  for(i in seq_along(div)){
    if(cs[i] < length(x)){
      x[ (cs[i] - div[i] + 1L):(cs[i] + 1L) ] <- x[ cs[i] + 1L ]/div[i]
    }
  }
  x
}

fill_na(df$val)
# [1] 15.0 20.0 18.0 22.0 20.0 20.0 20.0 20.0 20.0 14.0 23.0
#[12] 16.0 19.0 20.0 20.0 20.0 20.0 18.0 15.0 20.0 22.0 17.5
#[23] 17.5 17.5 18.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, however the peak value needs to be shared, so that for the first sequence (three NAs + the peak ) the sum of all four data points should be exactly 80 , before and after the process.

Comment: @DAL OK, corrected now, see the edit.

Comment: that's great, thank you.

Comment: could you please revisit your solution, it overwrites one extra value prior to the NA sequence. The 5th value is 17 originally, it is overwritten: 20. Thanks